# OpenLayers take user input of XY and create a point

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm looking to take input from a form (X and Y WGS84 coordinate) and then draw a point on my map when the user clicks execute.

I could not locate something like this in the OpenLayers examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just written down a short code for you where you can take x,y or lat,lon input from user in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) format to plot marker on map. Right now default input values are lat/lon for London but you can modify this code as per your requirement i hope it will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<title>OpenLayers - User input to create marker</title>
<style>
#map {
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, basemap, markers;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        init_map();
        $("#btn_addmarker").on("click", function () {
            var lat = $("#latitude").val();
            var lon = $("#longitude").val();
            add_marker(lat, lon);
        });
    });

    function init_map() {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Simple OSM Map");
        map.addLayer(basemap);
        markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
        map.addLayer(markers);
        map.setCenter(
            new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71.147, 42.472).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                map.getProjectionObject()
            ), 12
        );
    }

    function add_marker(latitude, longitude) {
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(longitude, latitude)
            .transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        );
        var point = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat);
        markers.addMarker(point);
        map.setCenter(lonLat, 8);
        //console.log(latitude + ", " + longitude);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="inputForm">Latitude:
  <input id="latitude" type="text" value="51.481383"/>
  Longitude:
  <input id="longitude" type="text" value="-0.087891"/>
  <input id="btn_addmarker" type="button" value="Add Marker" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devdatta/gdEgA/1/) which shows this in action.

Comment: Output is blank? I was expecting to see a map.

Comment: @SteveStaple you are right. The reason http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js is not a valid link anymore.please check http://jsfiddle.net/farhatabbas/gdEgA/26/