# Which is the correct OpenLayers JavaScript to import?

Tags: openlayers

In the OpenLayers examples online such as this one:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/accessible.html

I see them import the following script:

```
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js"</script>
```

However, in many places online such as this SE question:
[OpenLayers take user input of XY and create a point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74337/openlayers-take-user-input-of-xy-and-create-a-point)

I see them use this script for open layer:

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

What are the differences? Is it just a version difference? Why is one called ol.js and the other OpenLayers.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the differences? Is it just a version difference?

It is just a version difference as you suspected. `http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js` is for OpenLayers 2.x.

There was a rewrite at OpenLayer 3, and the .js file gets renamed to the shorter `ol.js`. (And so are the variables etc.)

There are **many** differences between openlayers 2 and 3+. Among them, some of the openlayers 2 functions are no longer provided in OpenLayers 3+ (due to a change of philosophy). See e.g. [Missing LayerSwitcher in OpenLayers3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/119713/34474) and other GIS.SE questions.